# Phaser texture atlas wrong dimensions

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I was using spritesheets in my game, but I had come to a problem, that I wanted my character to duck (to dodge bullets). I found out that I can use texture atlas. Based on what I have read, I thought, that this approach will resize the sprite,  based on its current animation. So when I would duck, the sprite would change its height, because the frame for ducking is less high that the frame for standing.

I load the atlas like:

```
game.load.atlasJSONHash('player', '../assets/images/player/player.png', '../assets/images/player/player.json');
```

I can see that the dimensions in the json are right, that the ducking frame height is 31 and the standing is 51.

```
"duck-right": {
            "frame": {
                "x": 20,
                "y": 0,
                "w": 19,
                "h": 31
            },
            "rotated": false,
            "trimmed": false,
            "spriteSourceSize": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "w": 19,
                "h": 31
            },
            "sourceSize": {
                "w": 19,
                "h": 31
            }
        },
"right": {
            "frame": {
                "x": 100,
                "y": 71,
                "w": 19,
                "h": 51
            },
            "rotated": false,
            "trimmed": false,
            "spriteSourceSize": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "w": 19,
                "h": 51
            },
            "sourceSize": {
                "w": 19,
                "h": 51
            }
        }
```

I create my player like this:

```
export default class Player extends Phaser.Sprite {
constructor({ game, x, y }) {
    super(game, x, y, 'player')
    game.physics.arcade.enable(this)
    this.body.bounce.y = 0
    this.body.gravity.y = 1200
    this.body.collideWorldBounds = true
    this.state = game.state.getCurrentState()
    this.anchor.setTo(0.5,1)

    //custom properties
    this.direction = 'left'
    this.isJumping = false
    this.isDucking = false
    this.isShooting = false
    this.isOnGround = false
    this.speed = 150
    this.lives = 2
    this.jumpSpeed = 350
    this.isInElevator = false
    this.activeElevator = null

    // set up animations
    //stand still
    this.animations.add('left', ['left'], 10, false)
    this.animations.add('right', ['right'], 10, false)
    //walk
    this.animations.add('go-left', ['go-left-1', 'go-left-2'], 10, true)
    this.animations.add('go-right', ['go-right-1', 'go-right-2'], 10, true)
    //shoot
    this.animations.add('shoot-left', ['shoot-left'], 1, false)
    this.animations.add('shoot-right', ['shoot-right'], 1, false)
    //duck
    this.animations.add('duck-left', ['duck-left'], 1, false)
    this.animations.add('duck-right', ['duck-right'], 1, false)
    //duck shoot
    this.animations.add('duck-shoot-left', ['duck-shoot-left'], 1, false)
    this.animations.add('duck-shoot-right', ['duck-shoot-right'], 1, false)
    //jump
    this.animations.add('jump-left', ['jump-left'], 1, false)
    this.animations.add('jump-right', ['jump-right'], 1, false)
    //jump shoot
    this.animations.add('jump-shoot-left', ['jump-shoot-left'], 1, false)
    this.animations.add('jump-shoot-right', ['jump-shoot-right'], 1, false)

    console.log(this.body)

    game.add.existing(this)
}
```

But the height is not changing with the animations. It does, but not correctly. Also the anchor(0.5,1) doesn't work, as when I duck, I duck on the top side of the sprite area, not the bottom.

Tried TexturePacker or alternatives, trim or not, always the same result. Can you at least confirm, that it shoul work as I am expecting? Eg. the anchor should work and the sprite should change its dimensions based on current frame?

Comment: Does disabling physics body on this sprite fixes anchor?

Comment: not sure what you mean, if you mean omit the line with arcade.enable(this) then I cannot do that easily as in many lines in my code I am referencing body